# Redirect any www domain with a 301

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been looking at this service here:

```
wwwizer.com
```

It redirects any non-www domain to the www equivalent and I was wondering if I could use a budget hosting account to do this myself via an `.htaccess`, which would work for any domain.

I am then planning to point my domains to this via www `CNAME` record so they always go to the naked version of the domain.

```
www.site.com -> site.com
www.lemon.com/test -> lemon.com/test
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use mod-rewrite in .htaccess this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.site.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://site.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.lemon.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://lemon.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

for any site should be something like this (not tested):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.(.+)$ [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://%1$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

Comment: This way you have to add a new entry for every site? Can we not do it so one command works for any site?

Comment: See my last edit, it's not tested but it should give you a point to start.